# ASP.NET MVC 3 passing parameter from view to jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a loop in my view and during the loop I want to pass the value to a jQuery and return the value back to the div.

View

```
@foreach (var item in Model){
    <p>@item.Title;</p>
    <div id="timeDisplay" onload="test(@item.DateTime);"></div>
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    function test(var datetime){
        $("#timeDisplay").html(datetime);
    }
});
```

The load function does work, what am I missing?

Comment: Your `test` function isn't accessible outside of `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `test` outside of `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(function () {
    // document ready stuff
});

function test(var datetime){
    $("#timeDisplay").html(datetime);
}
```

Instead of using the onload attribute, you would probably be better off using `$(document).ready()`. Also, please note that you have multiple divs with id timeDisplay - use a class instead.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <p>@item.Title</p>
    <div class="timeDisplay" data-date="@item.DateTime"></div>
  }

$(function () {
    // document ready stuff
    $(".timeDisplay").each(function() { 
        $(this).html($(this).data("date")); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the data attributes for something like this:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model){
    <p>@item.Title;</p>
    <div id="timeDisplay" data-DateTime="@item.DateTime">
    </div>
  }

 $(function () { //anyone know how to do this without the temp?
   var $el = $("#timeDisplay");
   $el.html( $el.data('DateTime') );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around your server data:

`onload="test('@item.DateTime');"`

Answer (score 1):

You should not create multiple elements sharing the same ID as you are doing in your example.

Also, your Javascript doesn´t make any since. It would be great to know what you´re aiming for here. This would be enough to display the item property;

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <p>@item.Title;</p>
    <div class="timeDisplay">@item.DateTime</div>
}
```

Comment: currently I have a js function that shows countdown timer when page loads. it generates targetDate and init() function gets executed.... It works fine e.g. 
>>targetDate = new Date("December 20, 2012, 13:00:00").getTime() / 1000;
>>init();

but what I am  trying to do is pass datetime via the loop and it should create its own countdown time, I hope it makes sense. thx

Comment: You can use a CSS `class` and create a jQuery function to generate the countdown for all elements with the `class`. See @jrummells answer where he´s using the `data` attribute.